# Are boot log messages anything to be worried about?

Tags: 20.04, logs

Before I log into my system (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), messages appear on my screen. On further investigation, I find them to be error messages. Here are the messages that appear on my screen before I log in (These are from the Logs app): [image: log messages that appear on my screen before logging in]

However, despite these messages, my system is working fine with no errors or issues that I can see. So, are most boot log messages anything to be worried about or they simply common error messages that I should just ignore? I tried researching on this site and the web but didn't find anything that related to my question.

If you need anything more, just ask.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The "fail whale" error happens when a message is logged by GNOME when something goes awry. If it is "dead" it means that there's not enough of the GNOME libraries running to display the error. You may find details in `/var/log/syslog`, though.

Comment: This will probably come in handy later, but I just really wanted to know if boot log messages that appear on the screen before the login screen appears are usually (note the 'usually') anything to worry about. Thanks!